# Why conditional operator will be treated as bool when passed in as a parameter?

Tags: c++, overloading, conditional-operator, function-parameter

I have two overloaded function

```
void foo(std::string value);
void foo(bool value);
```

when I call it with

```
foo(true ? "a" : "b");
```

why function takes a boolean will be called instead of string?

Comment: Does it take string as `std::string` or `const char *`?

Comment: Here is the two example: [`const char *`](http://ideone.com/FKyejs) and [`std::string`](http://ideone.com/AUIRya).

Comment: @m0nhawk it takes std::string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `bool` overload provides a better match, since you get an conversion between a `const char*` and `bool`. The string overload requires a conversion to a user defined type.

The conditional operator has nothing to do with it. For example,

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void foo(bool) { std::cout << "bool" << std::endl;  }

void foo(std::string) { std::cout << "string" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
  foo("a");
}
```

Output:

> bool

If you were to provide an overload

```
void foo(const char*) {}
```

then that one would be called.

Comment: so `void foo(const char*)` will return?

Comment: @Zigma it will be chosen over the other two overloads. It has the best match, because `"something"` decays to `const char*`.

Comment: @juanchopanza So if I want to call the one takes string with literal string, shall I do foo(std::string("a"))?

Comment: @ycshao yes, that would work. Or provide an overload taking `const char*`, that then constructs a string from that internally.